# Accordion clickable and hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make Accordion menu both clickable and hover?
In the following case, hover is working first time.
But, once click event triggered, the hover is not working

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/165/)

The the above demo, hover is working initially.
But if i try again after a mouse click, hover is not working

code here

```css
.accordion-body{
      display:none;
}

.accordion:hover div{
      display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
function expandAccordionBody(){
var myDivElement = document.getElementById("accbody" );
var cStyle=window.getComputedStyle(myDivElement, null);
if(cStyle.display=='block'){
myDivElement.style.display="none";
}else{
myDivElement.style.display="block";
}
}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="accordion">
                    <div onclick="expandAccordionBody()"> Head </div> 
                    <div id="accbody" class="accordion-body">
                       Body
                    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because it sets the inline css which has the more priority than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to slightly modify your code and use jQuery's `on` to bind `click` and `mouseover` events and `toggle` for element visibility for this to be achieved

```js
$("#acchead").on('mouseover click',function() {
  $("#accbody").toggle("show");
});
```

```css
.accordion-body{
      display:none;
}
.accordion:hover div{
      display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="accordion">
                    <div id="acchead"> Head </div> 
                    <div id="accbody" class="accordion-body">
                       Body
                    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged jQuery, I made this solution for you.

It works as followed:

When a moves his mouse over the head, the body is shown. When he leaves it, the body gets hidden.
When the user clicks on the head, the body is shown, and the hover is disabled. First he'll need to click the head again to close is, after that the hover works again.

I hope that this is what you are trying to achieve.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.accordion-body').hide();

  $('#acchead').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clickActive')) {
      $('.accordion-body').hide();
      $(this).removeClass('clickActive');
    } else {
      $('.accordion-body').show();
      $(this).addClass('clickActive');
    }
  }).on('mouseenter', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clickActive')) {
      $('.accordion-body').show();
    }
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clickActive')) {
      $('.accordion-body').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#acchead {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.accordion-body {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div id="acchead">Head</div>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    Body
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The "accordionbody" is not accessible, can we make it  available for on hover ?

Comment: Sure, instead of using `id="accbody"` I've changed it to `class="accordion-body"`... see the update

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.accordion:hover div{
      display:block !important;
}
```

As Shoaib Iqbal mentioned, inline css overwrites stylesheets, so you need the important to overwrite the inline css on hover.

Alternatively you could try adding and removing a class in your js on click function.
**JS:**

```
 if(myDivElement.className == "accordion-body open"){
        myDivElement.className = "accordion-body";//reset class
    }else{
        myDivElement.className = "accordion-body open";
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
#accbody.open{
      display:block;
}
```

Comment: That's because when you are clicking, you are still hovering, so the hover is still true. The only advantage is that when you are on a touchscreen device, you can still open/close the accordion. @user2555212

Answer (score 0):

## JS

```
if(cStyle.className.indexOf('block') == -1){
    myDivElement.className=myDivElement.className + " block";
}else{
    myDivElement.className = "accordion-body";
}
```

## CSS

```
.hover {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that hover CSS.

```
.accordion:hover div{
      display:block ;
}
```

Just add the `mouseout` and `mouseover` event for the `DIV`.

```
<div onclick="expandAccordionBody()" onmouseover="expandAccordionBody1()" onmouseout="expandAccordionBody2()"> Head </div>
```

And the JS function is:

```
function expandAccordionBody1(){
 var myDivElement = document.getElementById("accbody" );
 myDivElement.style.display="block";
}
function expandAccordionBody2(){
 var myDivElement = document.getElementById("accbody" );
 myDivElement.style.display="none";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Working code here  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yf4W8/184/)

Code can be improvised.

css

```
.accordion-body{display:none;}.accordion:hover div{display:block;}
```